# How to prevent a preference to be written when it is the same as the previous one?

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
struct ViewSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
    value = nextValue()
  }
}


extension View {
  public func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
    background(
      GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
        Color.clear
          .preference(key: ViewSizePreferenceKey.self, 
                      value: geometryProxy.size)
      }
    )
    .onPreferenceChange(ViewSizePreferenceKey.self, perform: { value in
      onChange(value)
      print("changed .......... ")
    })
  }
}
```

Every time a view is redrawn, the preference is written on the line

```
 .preference(key: ViewSizePreferenceKey.self, 
             value: geometryProxy.size)
```

But this is not good because 90% of the time, at least in my app, the view has the same size as before and I end with the preference being written zillions of times per frame and Xcode complains.

I want the preference to be written just if the read value is different from the previous one.

I can control that on the view, but I would like to know if there is a way to do that in the preference itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why Xcode would complain about a preference updating a lot. I feel like that's a normal thing that happens...

Anyway, I think [`equatable()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/equatable()) might help here.

> Prevents the view from updating its child view when its new value is the same as its old value.

Make an `Equatable` view, and have the `Color.clear` as its child. Its equality would depend on a `CGSize` property passed to it.

```
struct SizePreferenceSetter: View, Equatable {
    let size: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        Color.clear 
            .preference(
                key: ViewSizePreferenceKey.self, 
                value: size
            )
    }
}
```

If you put `equatable()` on it:

```
GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
    SizePreferenceSetter(size: geometryProxy.size)
        .equatable()
}
```

The `Color.clear` would not be updated unless `geometryProxy.size` changes.

Comment: simply B R I L L I A N T! Thanks!!!! I don't understand why all views have not already this behaviour as default!